# SQL Tables are listed vertically instead of horizontal on PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am trying to move my WordPress website to a server on Godaddy. I have moved all the files and while trying to move the database, I couldn't see all the table data. Upon a closer look, I found that it is showing the data vertically instead of horizontal and without any scroll button. Please have a look at the image below for a clear understanding of my problem.

[image: wp options table error]

The table I am trying to view is WP-options

The phpmyadmin also looks old and weird and it says Starfield technologies on the top.

Please help.

Regards,
Naser.

Comment: vertically? I think you should click "Browse" on that screen if you want to see your data guy....

Comment: Thank you so much @andre3wap, it works now! I never had such problems with phpmyAdmin, this is the first time, to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking tables or columns? If you are talking about columns, then you must click on **Browse** tab to view columns horizontally and data below it.